# I need it to do a few specific tasks

Tags: networking, internet

Im trying to find out if raspberry pi can

- access files through a local network on a main computer.
- get on the Internet through a browser and access things like Facebook, google drive, and a website called pyromancers.com/dungeonpainter

Also i would like to know if pdf files can be opened.

Comment: Flash does not work on any Pi models properly. There are hacks for the Pi2 but none of them are HW-accelerated and therefore slow.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please ask one question at a time. If you take your question apart and search for the little pieces one by one you will also find lots of good advice already posted. So please break it up, do some research and ask detailled questions.

Answer (score 2):

The raspberry pi is a computer. Equipped with an operating system it can do whatever computers do, including what you are suggesting and an infinity of other tasks.